# Scope confusion. Can't explain order of print statements in o/p

Tags: python

Why doesn't the first print statement give me '5 = 3'? This is from John Guttag's book. Can't get my head around it.

It looks like this by the way:

```
3 = 4
2 = 4
1 = abc
4 = 4
5 = 3
6 = <function g at 0x026B22F0>
1 = abc
```

Script:

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x = 'abc'
        print '1 =',x
    def h():
        z = x
        print '2 =',z
    x = x+1
    print '3 =',x
    h()
    g()
    print '4 =', x
    return g

x = 3
z = f(x)

print '5 =',x
print '6 =',z
z()
```

Comment: Fix your indentation

Comment: What does it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a function does not execute it, So after `f` is defined, `x=3` is executed.  The function `f(x)` is called and the result assigned to z.

During the `f(x)` call, two more functions are defined, then `x=x+1` is executed.  So the first print statement is `3 = 4`.

That should be enough to help you figure out the rest.

Comment: I didn't realize that calling f(x) in 'z = f(x) would execute the function. But now I can see that once f(x) is called it must print what is in the body of the f function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All the changes you do to `x` is limited to the local scope of function `f`. Unless you declare x global (`global x`), `x` will not change from being `3` in the global space.

Answer (score 0):

[From Python docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html):

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

For example, the `g` function should be like this if the goal is to change the global `x`:

```
def g():
    global x
    x = 'abc'
    print '1 =',x
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `f(x)` before you have the first top-level print statement, the first print statement is the first one executed in `f`. This explains all deviations from apparent lexical order.

Comment: That explains it very well. I didn't realize that the call would execute the function, but once I thought about it, it made sense. Thanks